# Convert SQL query to SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I would like to convert my query into SQLalchemy:

```
SELECT sel.ID,sel.URL,GROUP_CONCAT(sel.label_values) 
     FROM
        (
         SELECT table1.id as ID, table1.url as URL,CONCAT_WS(':',label 
          ,value) as label_values
         FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = 
              table2.media_id
         WHERE table1.type = "image" AND table1.id >= 0
         ORDER BY table1.id
         ) AS sel
     GROUP BY sel.ID
```

I tried something like this:

```
label_and_values_column = func.CONCAT_WS(' : ',table2.c.label, 
                 table2.c.value).label(name='label_and_values_column')

outer_join_select = select([table1, label_and_values_column])\
                                       .order_by(table1.c.id)\
                       .select_from(table1.outerjoin(table2))\
                             .label(name='outer_join_select')


all_ = func.group_concat(' : ',outer_join_select.id)\
         .label(name='all_label_and_values_per_media_id')
```

The last line gives me

```
Caught exception: Neither 'Label' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'id'.
```

I am using db connection with transaction with `engine.begin()` as `db_conn_transaction`:

```
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(db_conn_transaction)
```

I would like to construct `select_statment` and then use `select_statment.execute().fetchall()`

Can't use `.subquery()` since I don't have `session.query()...`

Any help for converting my query in SQLalchemy is welcomed!